# Header animated differently on separate pages using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a header.php file which is called into all of my pages, and within it there is this:

```
<header <?php if (is_page('Home')) { echo 'id="home-masthead" class="site-header" role="banner"'; } else { echo 'id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner"'; } ?>>
```

What this means, is that if I'm on the home page, I can style the header for just that page using `#home-masthead` in my CSS, and to style all other pages I can style the header with just `#masthead`.

My problem is that even though the php works giving my homepage header `id="#home-masthead" and all other pages`id="masthead"`, and the style works on those pages. When I try to animated the header id on any page but the homepage it doesn't work.

Here is my CSS:

```
#masthead {
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  /* other styles here */
}

.animate#masthead {
  height: 75px;
}
```

and my JS:

```
// Header Shrink

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 125;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
      $('#home-masthead, #masthead, #logo, #list-container').addClass('animate'); // header-animate
    }
    else {
      $('#home-masthead, #masthead, #logo, #list-container').removeClass('animate'); // header-animate
    }
  });
  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
```

**tl;dr** JS header animation only works on home page and not other pages, possibly due to the php code changing the id for pages other than the home page.

Comment: Does the class animated appear, even though it doesn't do the animation?

Comment: @monxas it is in my style.css file. Unless you mean something else? If so, how can I check if it appears?

Comment: with firebug or dev tools. Are you familiar with any of those? 

push F12 when looking at you page, and a new panel will appear. it's complex, but you'll get the hang of it. click the very first button on the top left of the new panel, now you can hover the mouse and parts of the web will highlight, while the code that matches the highlighted pert will do too. get to the body tag, and that is updated live. you can even modify html from there (it will dissapear on refresh of course)

Comment: @monxas thank you! It turns out that `.animate` does not even appear. However `#logo`  and `#list-container` both still animate.

Comment: Then it might be in the if? Does the if condition applies for sure? 'if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {' Probably for the home page that if returns false? Ill write an answer so I can format code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. the console.log should appear on the dev tools, on the console tab

```
if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
  console.log("entered if");
  $('#home-masthead, #masthead, #logo, #list-container').addClass('animate'); // header-animate
}
else {
  console.log("entered else");
  $('#home-masthead, #masthead, #logo, #list-container').removeClass('animate'); // header-animate
}
```

Comment: thank you! this worked, could you explain what the problem was and why this method made it work? If possible just link me to an article about the use of `console.log` in javascript, if you have time. Thanks again.

Comment: Cnsole.log doesn't modify your code's behaviour, it just logs into console text or variables. You must have fixed it by yourself editing something else. Take a look at chome dev tools or firbug if you're wuth firefox, they are a game changer when debuging js or jquery